# Pull GRUCell activations

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to get the GRUCell activaitons in my seq2seq model. Basically with the translate.py example, I am trying to see how the cells are getting activated. I have tried several variations of this trying to print the tensor but am not having any luck

```
test =    tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell_35/Cell2/GRUCell/add:0")
print(test.eval())
```

I keep getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'encoder0' with dtype int32
 [[Node: encoder0 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I've tried creating the 'encoder0' variable and passing it to the `eval(feed_dict=encoder)`

```
encoder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (len(encoder_inputs), 1),'encoder0')
enc_data = tf.Variable(encoder, trainable=False, collections=[])
sess.run(enc_data.initializer, feed_dict={encoder:encoder_inputs})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new placeholder which is unrelated to the one the seq2seq model uses and feeding it, so the seq2seq one still has no value.

Instead of getting tensors by name it might be better to change the seq2seq code to return you a reference to that tensor. Then you can fetch it in your normal session.run call and have the right thing happen.